# Django notification hq mark_as_read

Tags: python, django

I am using django-notifications-hq for make notifications working on a Django app.
I am having problems with the function "mark_as_read". What I am trying to achieve is to have a notification list and, when clicking on a notification, mark it as read and redirect to the url of the post.
The problem is that, basically, I am having problems with that.
I tried many different ways on the template such as:

```
<a href="{% url 'main:question_details' pk=notification.target.question.id slug=notification.target.question.slug %}?next={{notification.mark_as_read}}" class="text-reset notification-item">
        {% if notification.unread == True %}
            <div class="d-flex alert-warning">
        {% else %}
            <div class="d-flex">
        {% endif %}
            <div class="flex-1">
            <span class="text-dark small">Commento</span> 
            <span class="text-dark small float-end"><i class="mdi mdi-clock-outline"></i> {{notification.timestamp|naturaltime}}</span>
                <h6 class="mb-1">{{notification.verb}}</h6>
                <div class="font-size-12 text-muted">
                    <p class="mb-1">{{ notification.target.comment }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

In this case the redirect works but, as soon as I press the dropdown menu, the notification is already marked as read.
If I remove the `?next={{notification.mark_as_read}}` the redirect works but the notification isn't marked as read.
Anyone has ever worked with django notifications had an issue like that?

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to get a complete picture of what is going wrong from just the template snippet.

I can only conclude that there's no logic in `main:question_details` for actually setting `mark_as_read=True`. The `?next={{notification.mark_as_read}}` is just adding a bit of extra data into the request, a True or False, value. Not actually marking it as read.

And even if you did have logic in the detail view to do something if next=True, how would you know which notification to mark as read?

I would perhaps change the href from a link directly to the question_details, but rather a redirect view for notifications.

```
<a href="{% url 'main:open_notification' pk=notification.id" %}>
```

then have a simple view which is something like:

```
def open_notification(request, notification_id):
    notifcation = get_or_404(Notifcation, {"pk":notification_id, "recipient": request.user})
    notifcation.mark_as_read()
    return redirect(notifcation.target.get_absolute_url())
```

This means you can generalize the notification template, so there can be notifcations for whatever else, so long as the target of the notification has a url which it wants to redirect the users to.

The other option, is to have a `?next=url` query value to open_notification url, so you can say which url you want the user to be directed to after the notifcation has been marked as read, when rendering the `herf`.